# populate jList with folders?

Tags: java, swing, file, jlist

I was attempting to write a part of my code that would get the folders in a directory, and then use the names of those folders to populate a jlist, so that the user could select which folder from the ones in a specific directory they wanted to use. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the folders you could use `File.listFiles()` and then check if they are a directory by using `isDirectory()`.
Otherwise, but slightly more complex, you could use a `FileFilter`.

To populate it you save the file names in an array `String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};` and then create the jlist with them `JList dataList = new JList(data);`.